# Using a delegate to save values to core data

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

Beginner here, this is my first shot at using a delegate and I'm pretty confused - I'm trying to pass data between two controllers, the first of which is a tableview displaying some products, and the other is a modal view which allows the user to enter a new product to be displayed on that tableview. When the user hits "Save" in the modal view, I want to save the new product into core data and have it be displayed on the tableview.

The user enters information in three text fields in `AddProductController` (the modal view) and then hits save which calls `handleSave`:

```
func handleSave() {

    guard let newProductUrl = self.urlTextField.text else {
        print("error getting text from product url field")
        return
    }
    guard let newProductName = self.nameTextField.text else {
        print("error getting text from product name field")
        return
    }
    guard let newProductImage = self.logoTextField.text else {
        print("error getting text from product logo field")
        return
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.productSaveDelegate?.save(name: newProductName, url: newProductUrl, image: newProductImage)

        let companyController = CompanyController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(companyController, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Which in turn calls `save` in `ProductController` (the tableview):

```
func save(name: String, url: String, image: String) {

    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }

    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entity =
        NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Product",
                                   in: managedContext)!

    let product = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                  insertInto: managedContext)


    product.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
    product.setValue(url, forKey: "url")
    product.setValue(image, forKey: "image")


    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        products.append(product)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

If I'm understanding correctly, I'm using the delegate as a sort of link between the two so that I can pass the user-entered values directly into my `save` function? Correct me if I'm wrong I'm pretty new. But I create the delegate outside the class scope at the top of `ProductController` (the tableview controller) like so:

```
protocol ProductSaveDelegate {
    func save(name: String, url: String, image: String)
}
```

Then in `AddProductController` (the modal view where the user enters the new product information) I initialize the delegate near the top of the class:

```
var productSaveDelegate: ProductSaveDelegate?
```

And then use it to call the `save` function in `handleSave()` as seen above.

When I try to add `ProductSaveDelegate` to the class definition of `AddProductController` I get an error saying that `AddProductController` does not conform to the protocol.

What can I change here to make the user-entered product save to core data properly? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Make sure your **AddProductController**  looks like this -  `class AddProductController: UIViewController, ProductSaveDelegate {}` and you have to implement the protocol method in this class which is `func save(name: String, url: String, image: String)`

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are really cool and powerful, but sometimes, yeah, they can be confusing. You need to initialize the delegate inside of the `ProductController`, not the `AddProductController`.

This is a great image which shows how a delegate and protocol setup works:

[image]

Image from Andrew Bancroft's [website](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/04/08/how-delegation-works-a-swift-developer-guide/)

In this instance, your Delegate is your `ProductController` and your Delegator is your `AddProductController`

Answer (score 0):

**MAKE SURE YOU HAVE SUBSCRIBED THE DELEGATE**

Do NOT forget -

***classObject.delegate = self***

I suppose you are already familiar with the delegates,

You're get this error because, either you have `not implemented the delegate method` from the `AddProductController`(which in your case is false, as i can see it implemented), or you forgot to subscribe the delegate, to do so you need to make sure -

> 1. **Subscribing the delegate**, i.e. before transitioning to the next controller set the delegate to self like -

```
  // addProductController is the AddProductController Class's Object 

  addProductController.productSaveDelegate = self  
  self.navigationController?.present(addProductController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

also in the same class you need to implement the method defined in the protocol, i.e `func save(name: String, url: String, image: String)` in your case(already implemented)

You can also check a [small demo](https://github.com/saurabh-360/Protocol-Demo-Swift/tree/master/ProtocolDemo), i have impleted here for the protocols.